# Unable to pass java compiler parameters using maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins

As the title says I am unable to pass command line parameters to the java compiler using maven, I am using the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to do it, and accordingly to [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs) (specifically for the compilerArgs option of the pluging) I am using the *"latest way"* to speficy the arguments passed to the compiler. Well enough talk, more code, this is my maven configuration for the plug-in and I am not sure what am I doing wrong:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am following the instructions for the usage of the tool which says that `<fork>` have to be set to true, and I do not know what am I missing... a little bit of help please?

May or may not be helpful to mention that: I need the `parameters` argument as specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) because I want to get the name of the arguments in my methods in runtime using reflection; I use the -X argument when calling maven to see the debug and I shows me the "fork" call that it does and I cannot se ANYWHERE the arguments I am passing (maybe I need to enable the plug-in; but I think In this case is automatically enabled since it is not part of any profile, I am not a maven expert so please correct me if I am wrong).

**EDIT:** I have tried in several ways with and without the dash I have even tried the *"old way"* to do it:

```
<compilerArguments>
  <parameters />
</compilerArguments>
```

And:

```
<compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**My mistake:** I created the code before modifying my pom file, and ran it **using maven** to check that is was actually working. **After that**, I modified my pom to include the `-parameters` flag. The code had already been compiled **without** that flag and **was not modified after**. Therefore, maven saw no changes in the code and did not recompile the file.

**SOLUTION** execute a `mvn clean`, delete the compiled classes, delete the `target` folder, or whatever is necessary to ensure that the files are recompiled.

Answer (score 3):

Please mention, that you always have to write a '-' letter before 
the parameters.

Below you can see a configuration for your plugin with some sample 
compiler arguments.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-verbose</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: nope, I have tried that already and it didn't work, I have tried a lot of variants and nothing :(

Comment: Look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html   there you can see that you have to use dependency resolution to get it working

Comment: can you elaborate a bit in how to do that please

Comment: for what I am seeing is "auto-attached" to the compile phase (which I am obviously executing)

Answer (score 3):

From the [maven compile plugin main page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/):

> The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your project. Since 3.0, the default compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler (if you are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources. If you want to force the plugin using javac, you must configure the plugin option forceJavacCompilerUse.

I'm guessing the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` doesn't works the same way `javac` does with the `-parameters` option.

Try forcing the `javac` use

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I thought that too, but I was not able to find a difference when using the "native" compiler

Comment: Have you tried compiling without maven see if the option works?

Comment: Then, what about this?
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html