# Is it possible to get rid of @Param Annotation in Spring Data JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data JPA, when I want to write a custom query, if I specify a parameter, I send this parameter value with @Param annotation, Is it possible to get rid of @Param Annotation in Spring Data JPA Repository?

Example Query:

```
@Query("select u from User where u.name = :name")
User findUserByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Desired Query:

```
@Query("select u from User where u.name = :name")
User findUserByName(String name);
```

Note, I don't want to use ?0 or something like that I want to use directly name parameters.

Comment: Yes, you can. `@Param` is only required when method argument differs from query argument

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, thanks for your comment but when I don't use it, query gives error on run time.

Comment: what error exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. As the [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) describes:

> As of version 4, Spring fully supports Java 8’s parameter name discovery based on the -parameters compiler flag. By using this flag in your build as an alternative to debug information, you can omit the @Param annotation for named parameters.

And [Stackoverflow has an example how to do that with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345295/unable-to-pass-java-compiler-parameters-using-maven) (and probably for the build tool of your choice as well):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `-parameters` to the java compiler. When using gradle you can easily define this by:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs += ["-parameters"]
}
```